cmake libtorch build issue
I'm not used with working with cmake. Currently I'm building libtorch with cmake according to this guide here.
However during the build an error message appears
"CMake Error at C:/lib_sources/libtorch_extracted/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/select_compute_arch.cmake:227 (message):
Unknown CUDA Architecture Name 9.0a in CUDA_SELECT_NVCC_ARCH_FLAGS"
Now, there exist a possible solution listed here. However I have no idea how to implement the command. Simply calling it in cmd didn't work, modifying the CMakeList didn't work either (or rather, I dont know where to put this line in the file). Trying to use the cmake gui didn't work either.
Can anyone help me?
Also another question, the installation guide (the first link) is for a minimal build, can I access libtorch from another project via the import line in the .pro file? Or do I need to build more?
